# Kotlin TimerTask - How can I repeat the task every 5 seconds?

Tags: kotlin

I am looking to rrefresh a RecyclerView every 5 seconds, with the latest data from my webserver JSON (which is dynamically updated from server each call).

Whilst the timer works once, and carries out the call 5 seconds later, it does not repeat.

I have placed the below in my `onViewCreated` override of the fragment which I am displaying the data:

```
val funtimer: Timer = Timer()
        funtimer.schedule(timerTask(){
            jsonParse()
        }, 5000)
```

Each 5 seconds, I am hoping to repeat the `jsonParse()` call.

`jsonParse()` is in its own public function and this consists of the following code:

```
public fun jsonParse(){
        val args = this.arguments 
        val ctuid = args?.get("ctuid").toString()
        val servicedate = args?.get("date").toString()

        val url = "MYJSONSERVER/api/train.php?trainid=$ctuid&date=$servicedate"
        val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, {
            response ->try {
            trainList.clear()
            val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("timetable")
            for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                val serviceRow = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)

                //For simplification, some variables have been redacted
                val booked = serviceRow.getString("booked") 

                trainList.add(Traindata(booked))
            }

            recycleradapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity() , "No Services Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        }, {
                error ->
            error.printStackTrace()
        })
        requestQueue?.add(request)
```

In context, i'd like the recyclerview to be reloaded with the newest data from the server every 5 seconds, and whilst I can call `jsonParse()` directly on view loaded, i'd like to repeat this.

Any advice much appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, i've done a bit of research and it turns out theres a command `scheduleAtFixedRate`, so after implementing this, it appears to work correctly.

```
    val funtimer: Timer = Timer()
    funtimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        timerTask()
        {
        jsonParse()
    }, 5000, 5000)
```

Useful for anyone that is needing to reload a `RecyclerView` on a timer.

If anyone thinks there is a better way feel free to comment or answer. Thanks